# Is there a better way to use nested function in PROC SQL?

Tags: function, sas, proc-sql

I am doing something needs more than once query in `proc sql` so I try to write code perform like nest function in `data step`. Here is an example:
Data test have 2 variables, Group and Num.

```
data test;
  input Group$ Num;
  cards;
  A 10
  A 30
  B 10
  B 40
  C 30
  C 30
  ;
run;
```

Now I am **looking for which `Group` has the biggest mean value**. So firstly I compute mean for each `Group`, secondly get the max value of these means, Finnaly select the `Group` whose mean has the same value of the result in step 2.

```
proc sql;
  select Group, avg(Num) as Mean
  from test
  group by Group
  having Mean = (
    select max(mean) from (
      select avg(Num) as mean from test group by Group
    ) 
  )
  ;
quit;
```

Yes, I get the right answer, it's "C". But I don't like this method, it is too lengthy. The following code is wrong in syntax:

```
proc sql;
  select Group, avg(Num) as Mean
  from test
  group by Group
  having Mean = max(avg(Num))
  ;
quit;
```

But it is much beautiful, and shorter, too.
Do you have any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL `outobs=` option to your advantage, leveraging a descending sort.

```
proc sql outobs=1;
  select group, mean(num) as num_mean 
  from test
  group by group
  order by num_mean desc
  ;
```

A SAS SQL `having` clause with an aggregate function (`max`) will perform an automatic regmerge.

```
proc sql;
  select Group, num_mean
  from 
    (
      select group, mean(num) as num_mean 
      from test group by group
    )
  having 
    num_mean = max(num_mean)
  ;
```